# Bug in NMaximize in 12.2?

Tags: bugs, mathematical-optimization

**Bug introduced in 12.2, Fixed in 12.3**

Something changed in `NMaximze` in v12.2:

```
NMaximize[E^(-x^2) - 1, x]
(* {(-1 + E^#1)[0.], {x -> 0.}} *)
```

v12.1 works as expected:

```
NMaximize[E^(-x^2) - 1, x]
(* {0., {x -> 0.}} *)
```

as does `Maximize` in v12.2:

```
Maximize[E^(-x^2) - 1, x]
(* {0, {x -> 0}} *)
```

Do you all agree this is a bug?  Any ideas on a workaround?

```
$Version
(* "12.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)" *)
```

Comment: Consider: NMaximize[E^(-x^2.) - 1, x] This seems to return a reasonable numerical answer, so maybe this narrows down the location of the bug.

Comment: This is fixed in the 12.3 prerelease version `12.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 13, 2021)`

Comment: Here's a cute fix: `MapAt[Function, NMaximize[E^(-x^2) - 1, x], {1, 0}]`.  Not as good as ``Optimization`UseConvexMinimize = False`` though. (Not nearly, since it fails whenever `NMaximize` succeeds.) BTW, @bills, the convex minimizer rejects the problem with the exponent `2.` as "not transformable," and `NMaximize` falls back onto the old automatic method.

Comment: Since this is for a shared package, I used `If[$VersionNumber==12.2, Block[{Optimization\`UseConvexMinimize=False}, ...]` because you can never be sure what version of Mathematica people will be using.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems (clearly!) to be a bug in the preprocessing for the new convex optimizer. Use one of the other methods (e.g. `"DifferentialEvolution"`):

```
Trace[
 NMaximize[E^(-x^2) - 1, x],
 _Optimization`MinimizationProblem,
 TraceForward -> True,
 TraceInternal -> True
 ]
```

[image]

Workaround:

```
NMaximize[E^(-x^2) - 1, x, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]

(*  {0., {x -> -5.45643*10^-9}}  *)
```

Alternatively, you can turn off the convex minimizer:

```
Block[{Optimization`UseConvexMinimize = False},
 NMinimize[-(E^(-x^2) - 1), x]
 ]

(*   {0., {x -> -5.45643*10^-9}}  *)
```

Comment: Maybe just a missing `&` in there.  Thanks for the workarounds and I'll report to WRI.

Comment: @ChrisK Seems to be the added constant ("vertical shift") that triggers the bug.  Also occurs here: `NMinimize[1 + Log[1 + x^2], x]`.

Comment: This is fixed in the 12.3 prerelease version `12.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 13, 2021)`